# How to split sentence in to words and then separate it in to two groups in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, hashmap

I need to split sentence in to words and then in to two groups. One group should contain only last word in the sentence and other words belongs to second group as modifiers of the sentence.
Eg: 
Max Price Food Information
{Max, Price, Food} {Information}

I did it until splitting the words. But cound't group like that.How can I do it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Groupword {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordFreqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    terms.add("Max Price Food Information");

    for(int i=0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
      tempTerm = terms.get(i);
      String[] result = tempTerm.split(" ");
      for (String s : result) {
      System.out.println("word="+s);
    ...................................
    ...................................
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> firstWordsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> lastWordList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String tempTerm : terms) {
    int lastSpaceIndex = tempTerm.lastIndexOf(" ");
    if (lastSpaceIndex >= 0) {
        String firstWords = tempTerm.substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
        String lastWord = tempTerm.substring(lastSpaceIndex+1);
        firstWordsList.add(firstWords);
        lastWordsList.add(lastWord);
    }
    else {
        lastWordsList.add(tempTerm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to take an output using 'System.out.println("firstWordsList="+firstWordsList); 'But, It gave an error as,' java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1'. How can I solve it? Thank you very much @John Scattergood  .–

Comment: There was a typo in my answer.  It's fixed now.

Comment: I tried with it. Sorry. It also gave the same error. 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1'.

Comment: Do you have any terms with only one word and no spaces? If so then lastIndexOf() needs to be guarded against returning -1 before calling substring().  I'l update the answer.

Comment: Yes, my data set contain only one word. Now it is works well. Thank you very much. If I need to change this program for first word of term as a one group rather than last word.                                                                                          Eg:Max Price Food Information {Max } {Price, Food,Information}                                     Can I know what are the changes I need to do?

Comment: All you need to do is change the code to use indexOf() instead of lastIndexOf()

Answer (score 2):

```
    String lastWord = result[result.length - 1];
    String[] modifiers = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gave output as,                                                                                                    lastWord=Information
modifiers=[Ljava.lang.String;@789144

Comment: Use ```System.out.println("lastWord=" + lastWord + " modifiers=" + Arrays.toString(modifiers))```.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.copyOfRange`:

```
terms.add("Max Price Food Information");


for (String s: terms) {
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    String[] arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length-1);  // [Max, Price, Food]
    String[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length-1, arr.length); // [Information]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this solution **might** work , it's **not efficient**
if you have this **pattern** : 
Max Price Food Information
you could have **two array** :

```
String Data[][]=new String[3][terms.size];
String Information[] = new String[terms.size];
```

then reading data in following way :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0; i < terms.size(); i++){
    Data[0][i] = in.next();
    Data[1][i] = in.next();
    Data[2][i] = in.next();
    Information[i] = in.next();
}
```

this way is **without** split method

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the last word from the split words array and truncate the array's last element by copying it until length-1.

Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
  tempTerm = terms.get(i);
  String[] result = tempTerm.split(" ");
  for (String s : result) {
      System.out.println("word="+s);
  }
  String lastWord = result[result.length-1];
  result = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length-1)
}
```